# How to find out that SSIS installed in SQL Server using C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

I'm writing a Windows Form application using C#. I use

```
ssisServer = new IntegrationServices(ssisConnection);
```

to run and work with SSIS packages but before running the package I wanted to make sure the user runs the application in the correct system and SQL Server has the SSIS on it's SQL Server.

How can I find whether SSIS is installed on the server or not in C#?

Comment: You could check if the SSISDB exists on the server?

Comment: Yes I Think This is the good Solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the SQL Server Integration Services service is running on the server your connecting to.

```
SQL Server        Service Name
SQL 2008          MsDtsServer100
SQL 2012          MsDtsServer110
SQL 2014          MsDtsServer120
SQL 2016          MsDtsServer130
SQL 2017          MsDtsServer140
SQL 2019          MsDtsServer150
```

The name of the service will depend on what version of SQL Server you are connecting to. If the server was SQL Server 2019 then it would be MsDtsServer150 for example. You could simply check if the service exists and is running.

Add System.ServiceProcess to your project references (It's on the .NET tab).

```
using System.ServiceProcess;

ServiceController sc = new ServiceController("MsDtsServer150");

switch (sc.Status)
{
    case ServiceControllerStatus.Running:
        return "Running";
    case ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped:
        return "Stopped";
    case ServiceControllerStatus.Paused:
        return "Paused";
    case ServiceControllerStatus.StopPending:
        return "Stopping";
    case ServiceControllerStatus.StartPending:
        return "Starting";
    default:
        return "Status Changing";
}
```